# JavaScript - Pass second argument to ES6 Template whilst using .map

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am using es6 templates but have run into an issue when trying to pass a second argument to another template used internally within the original.

At first I was only using a `result.relevantJobTypes` argument but now I am trying to also pass the `result.id` for use within the template but I'm not sure how to do it because of the `map`.

```
var resultTemplate = ({ result }) => {
    return `
        ${result.id} 
        ${result.relevantJobTypes.length < 1 ? '' : `
            ${result.relevantJobTypes.map(jobType => jobTypeTemplate({
                jobType // , result.id -> I want to use result.id somehow in jobTypeTemplate
            })).join('')}
        `}
    `;
}

var jobTypeTemplate = ({ jobType }) => {
    // template code
}
```

**Update**

Trying to implement @Bergi's answer but the id is undefined within the `relevantJobTypes` template:

```
${result.relevantJobTypes.length < 1 ? '' : `
    ${result.relevantJobTypes.map(jobType => jobTypeTemplate({
        jobType
    }, result.id)).join('')}
`}

var jobTypeTemplate = ({ jobType, id }) => {
    // template code
}
```

**#2**

Finally got it, I had to update the signature of `jobTypeTemplate` to be `var jobTypeTemplate = ({ jobType }, id) => {` rather than `jobType, id`

Comment: @Jonasw I wouldn't call it a good practice, but yes you can place arbitrary expressions in the interpolation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just a standard function call, this has nothing to do with template literals. Instead of

```
jobTypeTemplate({
    jobType, result.id // SyntaxError
})
```

you will need to use

```
jobTypeTemplate({
    jobType
}, result.id)
```

for a second argument. Of course you could also put a second property in the object literal:

```
jobTypeTemplate({
    jobType,
    id: result.id
})
```

Comment: Why not result : result.id ?

Comment: thanks @Bergi, I'm assuming, I'd need to do the map in the `jobTypeTemplate` instead of where I have it just now?

Comment: @Jonasw Because the title was asking for a second argument, not another object property.

Comment: @martincarlin87 No, you don't need to change anything about the `map` call